# How to insert a value in a MySQL DB with a primary key of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, parent-child, parent

I have a Table quizz, with has an unique id.

I have a table questions

every question that i have should have the id of the quizz.

So 1 quizz has 6 questions, and every question has the id of the quizz.

So on insert of one question, the id of the parent quizz should be written to column quizz_id

```
quizz : id, name , type
questions: question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, ransw, ransw2, ransw3, ransw4, quizz_id
```

Comment: Fix your schema. A database table is not a function

Comment: Does some info which allows to select a quizz relative to a question exists? or quizz must be selected randomly?

Comment: I am creating a quizz, which means inserting the questions into the table questions. There are 2 types of quizzes, one has many correct answers, another one has only one. That is the type of the quizz.
Now, i write the questions into table questions, over a html form i write the question, its answers, what is correct answer and what i dont know how to do, the id of the quizz this question relates to. Does it help? column quizz_id from table questions should be the same value like the primary key of the table quizz, for this session. I am having difficulties finding info for such normal thing